# Characteristic exponent after Girsanov transformation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-transform, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion. Its characteristic exponent (or Fourier transform) is easily calculated to be
$$ \mathbb E [e^{ixB_t}] = e^{-\frac 12 x^2 t}. $$
Now I want to apply a Girsanov transformation with density $\exp(\int_0^t A_s d B_s - \int_0^t A_s^2 ds)$ for some predictable process $A_s$ satisfying Novikov's condition. It is well-known that $B_t-\int_0^t A_sds$ is Brownian motion under the new measure. However, I am more interested in the question what the characteristic exponent of the *old* Brownian motion under the new measure is. Is there an explicit way to calculate this? Same question, but differently phrased: Is there an elegant way to calculate
$$ \mathbb E [ e^{\int_0^t A_s dB_s} e^{ixB_t}]? $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Doob-Dynkin we have that $A_t=f(t,\{B_s\}_{0\leq s\leq t})$.

If $\mu_0$ is the law of Brownian motion then under the measure $\mu=\exp\left(\int_0^T A_sdB_s-1/2\int_0^T A_s^2 ds\right)\mu_0$ we have that the law of $B$ is the law of the solution to the (possibly path dependent) SDE $dX_t=f(t, \{X_s\}_{0\leq s\leq t}))dt+dB_t$. So computing the characteristic function is the same as finding the law of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, rephrasing as an SDE might help my application in the end. One small additional question: is there a way to guarantee that the characteristic function obtained this way is real-valued (if I assume $X_0=0$)? This would be most important for the application I have in mind.

Comment: And one easier question: Do you have a reference for such a statement? It does not seem completely obvious to me, why I can replace $B$ by $X$ in the argument of $f$ for the SDE.

Comment: Under $\mu$ we have that $B_t=\int_0^t f(s, \{B_s'\}_{0\leq s'\leq s}) ds+\tilde B_t$ where $\tilde B_t$ is a BM under $\mu$. I just relabel the variable $B$ as $X$. I am not sure about the characteristic function being real valued. I